# c# writing a huge chunk of the memory to a file and vice versa

Tags: c#

I want to copy a huge chunk of the memory of a game to a file to be used as a backup.
I believe I have to use filestream to write to the file and memorystream to write from the file to the memory again.

What's the best way todo this ?
I got 0x140000000 as the start address and 0x14A8A8200  (size: 0a8a8200)
This is quite a bit to copy So I got no idea how to get started.

I guess byte array of start to end address and filestream writing ?

tips and help is much appreciated

Edit:
I noticed Cheat Engine has this function called save/load memory region

Comment: haven't started yet as I'm stuck on how to make the chunk of memory into a byte array, I'm not that advanced in c# and I try to envision it in my head first

Comment: @BertPauwels: where did you find those addresses?

Comment: a Task manager app, I double checked it with a debugger and the addresses/size are correct

Comment: Side note: PInvoke is not the easiest topic in C#/.Net... You may be better off using existing solutions to cheat...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Makes a good point regarding p/invoke. If you start writing this in C#, when it doesn't work you'll wonder is it the p/invoke that I got wrong, or the API calls. So I'd always start with C++ code to work out what API calls are needed. Once that's ironed out, then translate to C# and p/invoke.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to p/invoke the native API to do this. That API is [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx). You cannot read the memory from plain user mode code because the memory is in a different process and so is protected by the virtual memory system. Consequently you need help from the OS, and that's what `ReadProcessMemory` does for you.

You will also need to obtain a handle to the process. Call [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) for that. You'll need to include `PROCESS_VM_READ` in order for the call to `ReadProcessMemory` to succeed, as described in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx):

> The handle must have `PROCESS_VM_READ` access to the process.

Your call to `ReadProcessMemory` also needs a pointer to a block of memory in which to store the returned buffer. You can use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, or perhaps more easily allocate a byte array and pin it.